# how do delete, from a file, all the lines containing some text and the lines immediately following those

Tags: php

I'm not so good in php anymore..
I know this is an easy one but I'm getting lost in the code I found around as a solution.

I need to modify a file removing some lines: when matching a string in a line I need to remove that line and the line following that one.

```
  /*$file already received via curl*/  
  file_put_contents("orig", $file);  

  /*missing part removing the lines*/
  $file ... remove lines containing "STRING" and the line following those  

  /*do some other manipulation*/
  $file = str_replace("aa","bb",$file);
  $file = str_replace("cc","dd",$file);

  /*preparing the file*/
  $output = "modified";
  file_put_contents($output, $file);

  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($output));

  /*returning the file*/
  readfile($output);
  exit;
```

so for example in the file

```
1  gooo aaaaaaaaaaa
2  ----------------
3  jlfjsdfjjfas
4  lkflkdsafòklaf
5  gooo ljlkjlklkjl
6  jlfkjsdlkfjlskdjflksd
7  òfnsdòafdnòaf 
8  flksjflksdajfòalk
```

searching for "gooo" the output file would contain lines 3 4 7 8

```
3  jlfjsdfjjfas
4  lkflkdsafòklaf
7  òfnsdòafdnòaf 
8  flksjflksdajfòalk
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. It's better to read and write your files line by line using [fgets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and [fputs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputs.php) rather than loading the entire input file into memory, and essentially create a copy in memory, minus a few lines.

```
<?php
//Path to input file
$inFilePath = 'test.txt';

//Path to output file
$outFilePath = 'test_out.txt';

//Create file handles for our input and output files
$inHandle = fopen($inFilePath, 'r');
$outHandle = fopen($outFilePath, 'w');

//Define the search string
$searchTerm = 'gooo';

//Keep count of bytes written (it's a freebie) so we don't need to call filesize
$outFileSize = 0;

//If we have a good handle, do the business
if ($inHandle)
{
    //Define a flag to keep track of whether or not to skip the next line
    $skipNext = false;

    /*
     * Read our file one line at a time, so we don't pull the whole thing into memory
     */ 
    while (($currLine = fgets($inHandle)) !== false)
    {
        if($skipNext)
        {
            //If we're skipping this line, reset the skip flag and move to the next iteration
            $skipNext = false;
            continue;
        }

        //Search for the string, and if we find it, set the skip flag and move to the next iteration
        if(strpos($currLine, $searchTerm)!==false)
        {
            $skipNext = true;
            continue;
        }

        //If we're here, we have a valid line. Write it to the out file and update our byte count
        $outFileSize += fputs($outHandle, $currLine);
    }

    //Close our handles
    fclose($inHandle);
    fclose($outHandle);
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: '.$outFileSize);

/*returning the file*/
readfile($outFilePath);
exit;
```